# how to load remote data to select2 and search by title

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I have some data i return using (FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) in my query. I call this query on my server side (mvc controller) to get json data, so i could later load it into select2 in my view.

I use this code in my movies controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DisplayMovies()
    {
        Movies [] movieList = await movieStorage.GetAllMovies();

        if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return Json(movieList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

When i debug this code, debugger returns json like this:

```
[{"Title": "Shawshank Redemption", "Director": "Frank Darabont", "Genre": "Drama", "ReleaseYear": "1994", "Rating": "9,3"},
{"Title": "Shutter Island", "Director": "Martin Scorsese", "Genre": "Mystery", "ReleaseYear": "2010", "Rating": "8,1"},
{"Title": "Pulp Fiction", "Director": "Quentin Tarantino", "Genre": "Crime", "ReleaseYear": "1994", "Rating": "8,9"}]
```

**this is my .js**

```
var myUrl = '@Url.Action("DisplayMovies", "Movies")';
$('.myMovies').select2(   {
    placeholder: 'Select movie...' ,
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    ajax: { 
        url: myUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                searchTerm: term
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {                                                     
            return {results: data};
        }
    }
});
```

and **html**

```
<select class="myMovies" multiple="multiple">
</select>
```

However when i run it, there is no result and no error in console in chrome or firefox.

**If i change my movies controller to something static like that, it suddenly works:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DisplayMovies()
    {
        var list = new[]
        {
            new { id = 0, title = "Shawshank Redemption" },
            new { id = 1, title = "Shutter Island" },
            new { id = 2, title = "Pulp Fiction" },
        }.ToList();

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            Object json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
            return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Why does this work, but not when i get data from database? Where is the error? Is the json that i get from database not correct, or is it javascript code - select2 for displaying json?

Please help

Comment: your json is different in your cases.  have you tried to select into an anonymous object that looks like the object that works?

Comment: any examples? i don't really know what you mean @Fran

Answer (score 1):

So this call

```
Movies [] movieList = await movieStorage.GetAllMovies();
```

return this json

```
[{"Title": "Shawshank Redemption", "Director": "Frank Darabont", "Genre": "Drama", "ReleaseYear": "1994", "Rating": "9,3"},
{"Title": "Shutter Island", "Director": "Martin Scorsese", "Genre": "Mystery", "ReleaseYear": "2010", "Rating": "8,1"},
{"Title": "Pulp Fiction", "Director": "Quentin Tarantino", "Genre": "Crime", "ReleaseYear": "1994", "Rating": "8,9"}]
```

It does not match the json that works which is

```
[
{"id": 0, "title":"Shawshank Redemption"}
...
]
```

So shape your query response to match the structure that does work.

```
Movies [] movieList = await movieStorage.GetAllMovies()
    .Select((v,i) => new { id = i, title = v.Title }).ToArray();
```

Comment: oh i understand now. ok, i will try this and come back to you!

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://select2.github.io/options.html#my-objects-dont-use-id-for-their-unique-identifiers-what-can-i):

> **My objects don't use id for their unique identifiers, what can I do?**
>
> Select2 requires that the id property is used to uniquely identify the options that are displayed in the results list. If you use a property other than id (like pk) to uniquely identify an option, you need to map your old property to id before passing it to Select2.
>
> **My objects use a property other than text for the text that needs to be displayed**
>
> Just like with the id property, Select2 requires that the text that should be displayed for an option is stored in the text property. You can map this property from any existing property using the following JavaScript.

You need to return some sort of `id` with your records from your DB so you can use it with with select2. Then you map your results like this:

```
results: function (data, page) {
    var data = $.map(data, function (obj) {
        obj.id = obj.someID;//some id you don't have right now
        obj.text = obj.Title;
        return obj;
    });
        return {results: data};
}
```

Comment: so basically without returning some sort of id, this is impossible to do?

Comment: Seems so. May be you can use `Title` as `id` if it's unique.

Comment: title is just a string / nvarchar(255) in database